API document so I can control my safe wallet with curl
I want to control safe wallet through API with curl, so I need more details about how to use such API. hope there will be a step by step tutorial https://github.com/safe-global/safe-docs/issues/550

You can find a complete API reference on Safe documentation. You can also use a library like ethers to encode data. Note if you don't want to use cURL but would like to control your safe in the context of an app, the API Kit and Protocol Kit were specifically designed for that.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Hello, I have some questions about Create-Multisig-Transaction: https://docs.safe.global/core-api/transaction-service-reference#Create-Multisig-Transaction.

what's the field safe for?
how can I encode data if I want send erc-20 tokens?
what's the difference with sender and orignal
how can I get the signature?
when weill fillincontractTransactionHash ?



This is the address of the safe you want to create a transaction in. 2. You can find a detailed example of how to create the data field here: https://community.infura.io/t/ethers-js-how-to-send-erc-20-tokens/6721. 3. sender and origin could be different in the context of sponsored transactions using EIP-4337. 4. Owners of the Safe need to sign the transaction in order for it to be executed; this can be done just like when signing any other transaction from your Safe, or from the Protocol Kit: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/reference/safe#signtransaction.



You can get the transaction hash using the Protocol kit as well: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/reference/safe#gettransactionhash. It seems that you would benefit from the API Kit and Protocol Kit to achieve what you want, as the Transaction Service (which you try to be using directly) is less focused on developer experience and more on interacting with the different automated services that compose the Safe technical stack. I hope that this answered your question(s); if yes please don't hesitate to mark the question as solved here. Thanks in advance! Best, Louis


For the signature , When I use safe wallet ui I found the payload should be? To:
0xa7f77...8D6e4
Value:
0
Data:
0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000ce85f0d768bc8cddd85d523a5e926ab0999a5d570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e80000
Operation:
0
SafeTxGas:
0
BaseGas:
0
GasPrice:
0
GasToken:
0x00000...00000
RefundReceiver:
0x00000...00000
Nonce:
4

If I want to sign manually, what content should I choose?

Hello Louis, If I want to sign this signature with cast how can I get my inputs?

I want to control my safe wallet only with Safe Transaction Service, but I can not use API Kit or Protocol Kit. All the request payload will sign or build manually. Is it possible for me?

Yes it is possible, you will have to create the transaction manually; the inputs from Wallet UI (and/or transaction builder) can help you achieve this.
